# Return a data frame subset based on similar (not identical) elements in a vector?

Tags: r, string-matching

I have a dataframe (dim 2914 x 6) where one column is a vector of animal groups and species abbreviations, e.g. "bird_F.pw", and I have a separate vector of a few species abbreviations, e.g. "F.pw". I am trying to extract all rows of data where the animal group and species abbreviation from the data frame are **similar** to the abbreviation (i.e., I don't know the prefixes). I want to use operators like %in% and %like%, but I'm having trouble finding a way to generate non-identical matches.

Here's a sample dataframe:

```
df<-cbind(
c("A","B","C","D","E"),
c(1:5),
c("insect_F.vp","bird_L.ts","insect_P.qr","insect_V.cl","bird_H.dw"))
colnames(df) <- c("season","survey_id","pollinator")
```

And here's the vector of abbreviations I would like to search for within that dataframe:

```
abbrevs <- c("L.ts","P.qr","H.dw")
```

My anticipated outcome is:

```
output <- cbind(c("B","C","E"),c(2:3,5),c("bird_L.ts","insect_P.qr","bird_H.dw"))
colnames(output) <- colnames(df)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you don't want to bother with regular expressions, you can use these alternatives. Here's a tidyverse one

```
find_any_fixed <- function(x, patterns) {
  purrr::map(patterns, ~stringr::str_detect(x, stringr::fixed(.x))) |> purrr::reduce(`|`)
}
```

and here's a base R version

```
find_any_fixed <- function(x, patterns) {
  Map(function(.x) grepl(.x, x, fixed=TRUE), patterns) |> Reduce(`|`, x=_)
}
```

In both of these solutions I make sure to use the "fixed" option because "." means something special when you are using regular expressions. Since you seem to want to match the period exactly, you need to let the searching tools know that you are not using a regular expression

You can use this to find matching patterns. These examples assume `df` is a data.frame (`df <- as.data.frame(df)`). For example

```
find_any_fixed(df$pollinator, abbrevs)
# [1] FALSE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE
```

And you can subset with it

```
# Tidyverse
df %>% filter(find_any_fixed(pollinator, abbrevs))
# Base R
subset(df, find_any_fixed(pollinator, abbrevs))
```

Answer (score 3):

Here are two solutions, base R and with package `stringr`. The main trick is the create a compound pattern with alternatives (`"|"`). This is done with `paste`. The dollar sign matches the end of the string so `abbrevs` must end the data being searched for it.

```r
df <- data.frame(
  season = c("A","B","C","D","E"),
  survey_id = 1:5,
  pollinator = c("insect_F.vp","bird_L.ts","insect_P.qr","insect_V.cl","bird_H.dw")
)
abbrevs <- c("L.ts","P.qr","H.dw")

pat <- paste0(abbrevs, "$", collapse = "|")

# base R
i <- grepl(pat, df$pollinator)
# package stringr
j <- stringr::str_detect(df$pollinator, pat)

df[i, ]
#>   season survey_id  pollinator
#> 2      B         2   bird_L.ts
#> 3      C         3 insect_P.qr
#> 5      E         5   bird_H.dw

df[j, ]
#>   season survey_id  pollinator
#> 2      B         2   bird_L.ts
#> 3      C         3 insect_P.qr
#> 5      E         5   bird_H.dw
```

<sup>Created on 2023-08-24 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: This would also match values like "insect_Hxdw". It's not likely to occur, but the `.` would be a wildcard here.

Comment: In your `paste0` call, you could do something like `paste0("\\Q", abbrevs, "\\E$", collapse = "|")` to prevent the regular expression engine from interpreting `.` or other regular expressions patterns between `\Q` and `\E`.

Answer (score 3):

In base R we could use `apply` family:

1. Transform the matrix df into a data frame.
2. With sapply and grepl, we can identify which rows contain each abbreviation.
3. We then use apply with MARGIN = 1 to check if any of the abbreviations match for each row.
4. Finally, we subset using df[...] based on the apply(matches, 1, any) logical vector.

```
df <- df <- as.data.frame(df)

df[apply(sapply(abbrevs, function(x) grepl(x, df$pollinator)), 1, any), ]


  season survey_id  pollinator
2      B         2   bird_L.ts
3      C         3 insect_P.qr
5      E         5   bird_H.dw
```

Answer (score 1):

I think a simple solution here would be to use `endsWith`. It is both readable and vectorized:

```r
df[sapply(df$pollinator, \(x) any(endsWith(x, abbrevs))),]
```

For each element of `df$pollinator` you check if that element ends with any values from `abbrevs`. `sapply` will return a logical vector that you can use to filter rows.

**Output**

```
  season survey_id  pollinator
2      B         2   bird_L.ts
3      C         3 insect_P.qr
5      E         5   bird_H.dw
```